# Java swing GUI creation

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java GUI and I need:

1. A label in first row(only one label).
2. Starting 2nd row need to add say 100 buttons which extends to multiple lines(width shouldn't go beyond the visible screen)
3. In a new line one more Label
4. From next line say 100 buttons which extends to multiple lines(width shouldn't go beyond the visible screen)...
5. [OPTIONAL] If the components exceeds JFrame height then need a scroll facility to the main window (only vertical)

I have a strange results with flow layout, sometimes it stick to visible width, sometimes it sets even 500 buttons in a single row.

I have tried every layout and also multipanes. Still no luck.

Please guide.. **just need an idea, No need of code**

**Updated with code**: Sorry guys, that was my first question to **stackoverflow**

Thanks for prompt response
Infact i tried many, here is a simple one.

```
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("JAVA GUI");
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);       
    add(new JLabel("row 1"));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){     
        panel1.add(new JButton("b"+i));         
    }
    add(panel1);
```

Here the panel1 is appearing in a sigle row which goes beyond the visible part of the screen.

I think this can be solved by setting maximumsize to Jframe, but no idea how to set its size to FULL SCREEN.

Comment: do you have code currently ?

Comment: If you have code that's not working wouldn't it be better if you posted the code so that people could help you with what's wrong with it?

Comment: Of-course it's better. But I fed up with 100's of changes. Hence updated a simple one which make's me feel strange. Please check it out and suggest.

Comment: Are you a beginner at Swing ? IIRC from my old days of Swing programming, I think you should use a contentPanel. Is your code inside a JFrame directly ?  What happens if you setVisible after you've added everything ?

Comment: Hello Pierre, 
yes, i'm a begginer.
As i said this is just simulated to povide here, this is not my actual program

Comment: What about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack() also ? And okay I wanted to know if you were aware of some stuff before I tried to find solutions. Try pack() and setVisible(true) at the end of your code, I remember that was often the way to force stuff inside windows.

Comment: Found the solution with a working example, you'll have to play a little bit more and read A LOT of docs to get everything, but the basics I remember in my very soul is: NEVER ADD ANYTHING ON THE JFRAME directly. And also not setVisible too soon.

Comment: pierre, how to set the window to maximised size initially.

Comment: Thanks pierre.. Will keep it in my mind as a funda...

Comment: See my edit, I corrected it to maximize the window (I found the answer on StackOverflow xD)

Answer (score 0):

You can try MigLayout.
http://www.miglayout.com/

Also this question is not really a question for stack overflow. A good way to ask your question would be to post your code and tell us what is wrong with it and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi!
Infact I like to bound with in JAVA API's only for such a simple job.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the norm for 'good' stackOverflow questions, I don't have any problem with it myself.  Some people cannot deal with anything except code.  I would suggest that, if you're going to post code, that you take the trouble to post code that will compile, run, and demonstrate your situation.  It really helps those of us out here understand what you're seeing and what you're trying to do.

You talk about "rows"; be aware that rows and columns are terms used with things like GridLayout and GridBagLayout, but I don't think they're appropriate for what you describe.

In your description, you don't say what you want scrolled.  It would appear you want the entirety of the UI scrolled, I'll assume that for now.

I would try a JPanel with BoxLayout, oriented vertically, for the overall main UI.  You will put some things into that:

The first JPanel.

Another JPanel, set with FlowLayout, holding the first bunch of buttons.

Another JPanel with the next JLabel

And a fourth JPanel, set with FlowLayout, holding the second bunch of buttons.

Now, I would put the top-level panel into a JScrollPane, and then put that into the CENTER section of a Frame (with its default BorderLayout), and see what happens.  To tell the truth, I'm not sure, but these are the things I would start with.

I cannot tell, without running code, why you get odd behavior sometimes.

Comment: I tried this hundreds of times over the past week, The point where i stuck is the moment I use JScrollPane, the buttons in the subpanels are aligning only in a single line with horizontal scroll enabled. I want to restrict the scroll to only vertical. Please check if you can help?

Comment: I've posted my own question on this topic to SO; the only answer I've gotten so far is to use WrapLayout (written by well-known Swing expert Rob Camick) instead of FlowLayout.  He identifies the problem with FlowLayout: it wraps things without adjusting its own height.  Mr. Camick evidently thought it best to write a new layout manager for this purpose.  If someone comes with a reasonable way to do this from within the Swing library, I'll post again, but I imagine if there had been such a way he would have known about it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a previous comment, using a ContentPane is the way to go. Here is a working example of what you want:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("JAVA GUI");

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        int nbLines = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; i++) {
            JPanel linePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            linePanel.add(new JLabel("row " + i));
            for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                 linePanel.add(new JButton("b" + j));
            }

            panel1.add(linePanel);
        }

        frame.setContentPane(panel1);

        //frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here is what I get:

[image: Here is what I get]

If you want to have left-aligned buttons you can use:

```
JPanel linePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Comment: that's really made me aware of the difference of using JFrame directly

Comment: But how to make the label only component in first line

Comment: pierre... this is the problem. Please try below code
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
       JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());       
       panel2.add(new JLabel("row 1"));
       for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
           panel3.add(new JButton("b"+i));
       }
       panel1.add(panel2);
       panel1.add(panel3);

Comment: add the label to panel2
add the buttons to panel3
then add panel2 and panel3 to panel1

Comment: You'll have to read a bit more: you create first your content pane: IT will be the root of everything. Then in this panel, you'll be able to add various subpanels: on for each "row", in wich you had your label and buttons. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: when I add subpanel with buttons. then it's stretching all the way in a single line.

Comment: pierre,  got your point, In-fact that was what i was trying all the week. When i do so the panel containing buttons is appearing in single line stretching beyond the window. Please advise

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, I edited the sample to do that with several lines, how does it work for you ? I found how to do it there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html, they explain how each layout works.

Comment: Even i had a look at that link few days back (Not helped). The problem i encountered with boxlayout is "It's allocates the same size to all of it's sub panels, doesn't mind how many components in them".
It seems your PC screen size is more than my PC.Try increasing buttons count to 100 you will come to know the problem. Also try with nbLines value as 3.

Comment: Pierre, I have been observing a strange behaviour all the week. If this can be cleared then I can achieve my target.
"The moment I add the panels to a panel which is scroll eabled(panel added to JScrollPane) then the flowlayout components are going in single line by using horizontal scroll. If the scroll is restricted to only vertical then I can reach my target. Please help.